# Why 1-methylethanol is not preferred IUPAC name for isopropyl alcohol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, alcohols

For the compound $\ce{CH3-CH(OH)-CH3}$ I propose two names: **propan-2-ol** and **1-methylethanol**. Which is the correct name as per the IUPAC guidelines?

According to *Organic Chemistry* by Morrison and Boyd, the name is given as propan-2-ol. Why is 1-methylethanol not accepted?

Comment: I am in prefer of the latter name to be correct by giving more priority to the functional group rather than number of carbons .

Comment: The Wikipedia does a pretty reasonable job of explaining this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IUPAC_nomenclature_of_organic_chemistry#Alcohols and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IUPAC_nomenclature_of_organic_chemistry#Order_of_precedence_of_group

Comment: The name is derived from the longest carbon chain - in this case propyl. 1-Methyl ethanol is incorrect.

Comment: As side note, chemistry.se's page [resources for learning chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37303/resources-for-learning-chemistry/155812#155812) includes a dedicated section «References about Nomenclature», too.  You might want to start reading the 4-page summary, or the brief guide; both illustrated and published open access as .pdf.

Comment: "*Confusion regarding Nomenclature*" is a horrible title (it's not even a question — it's a complaint), and please don't use math mode where it makes no sense, e.g. for plain text. When citing third-party sources, make sure your citation is complete and unambiguous so that others don't have to guess your textbook's edition, year and page number your are referring to.

Comment: @buttonwood As another side note, links to the guides can also be found when you click on the "nomenclature" tag and then on "Lern more …". I don't know if that's easier, though.

Comment: @Long Indeed, this is new for me. Perhaps because I did not use tag «nomenclature» as often as possible (homework for me). Briefly, I compared the two .pdf documents the tag points to (2015  vs 2020) with [diffpdf](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/diffpdf) and leave it with «their organization to present the material is different» *assuming* the rules by 2015 are those in the 2020 document. Because your name is seen frequently when answering these questions. possibly you know better. For a quick look on the 4-page summaries and access to all Color Books, I liked the link to the resource page.

Comment: @Waylander , yeah that would be correct but there is also a rule that no matter of the longest carbon chain , the numbering should start from the carbon which is nearest to functional group . So we should start naming it from mid carbon as it's nearest to alcohol group .

Comment: Please reference this rule you to which you allude, Get_Maths.  Perhaps you mean that 2-hexanol should not be named 5-hexanol. If so, then the lower number is secondary to the chain length. @Waylander

Comment: No carbon chain can ever be 1-substituted with a carbon-based substituent, because that means the chain itself is one carbon longer than you originally said.